# How should I name new members added by Mono.Cecil?

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil

I'm using Mono.Cecil to add some fields and methods to various types, and I'm wondering how I should name the members to avoid conflicts with existing members. Do I need to go through every field, method, and property to do a string comparison for each member I want to add, or is there a way to have Cecil automatically choose a free member name for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use meaningful names, for debugging purposes (for example when those names might appear in stack traces). However, to avoid conflicts with existing members you might want to use characters that are not allowed in C# identifiers. For example you might name your field like this: `<YourLibraryName>_MeaningfulFieldNameHere`. That's what C# compiler itself does for compiler-generated members (like backing field for a property).

Comment: Meaningful names are great, but if someone had run my modifier on an assembly they didn't have the source for and it had broken the assembly, it would have been pretty catastrophic. Using invalid characters is an excellent solution. Not 100% fool proof, but I'd be more likely to create a bug when modifying methods to use the field anyway.

Comment: Note that I also suggest to use more or less unique prefix (YourLibraryName) to reduce chances of collision even more.